# messaging.onMessage (web use case) never gets invoked

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to consume web notifications fine for the setBackgroundMessageHandler use case without issue.

However when I try to consume notifications when my chrome browser tab is selected/active, the messaging.onMessage is never called.

The server is always sending the message:

```
{"multicast_id":*********,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:*********"}]}
```

Chrome version: Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is how I am configuring firebase in my page:

```
var messaging;


var config = {
    apiKey: "*************",
    authDomain: "*************",
    databaseURL: "*************",
    projectId: "*************",
    storageBucket: "*************",
    messagingSenderId: "*************",
    appId: "*************"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
messaging = firebase.messaging();
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    console.log('Messaging supported!!!!');//excutes, so messenging supported
    messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
        console.log('Message received. ', payload);//never invoked :(
    });
}
```

And for completeness, firebase-messeging-sw.js which is working well:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    ...
    ...
}
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': "*************",
  'apiKey': "*************",
  'projectId': "*************",
  'appId': "*************",
  'authDomain': "*************",
  'storageBucket' :"*************"
  });

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    //gets called :)
});
```

Any ideas or debugging hints?

Comment: Figured it out, my firebase library versions were different between client and firebase-messenging-sw.js

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, my firebase library versions were different between client and firebase-messenging-sw.js